# Distorted Image in Secondary Capture DICOM file

Tags: c++, dicom

I want to create a secondary capture DICOM file as per the requirements.
I created one, but the image( pixel data in the tag 7FE0 0010 ) looks distorted. I am reading a JPEG image using Gdiplus::Bitmap and using API ::LockBits and 'btmpData.Scan0' to get the pixel data. The same is inserted into the pixel data tag - 7FE0,0010. But while viewing the same in a DICOM viewer, it is coming as distorted. The dicom tags Rows, Columns, PlannarConfiguration are updated properly. BitsAllocated, BitsStored and HighBit are given values 8,8 and 7 respectively.

While goggling I came to know that, instead of RGB format, the bits might be in the order BGR. Hence I tried to switch the bits in the place 'B' and 'R'.
But still the issue exist. Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you forgot to take into account `Stride` support from GDI+. An image being much more explicit than 1000 words here is what I mean:[image], the actual full article being [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/graphics/using-lockbits-in-gdi/).